# determining if a matrix of linear forms represents a non-degenerate matrix

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra

Let $k$ be a field with $p$ elements. Consider the following computational problem

> *Input*: a natural number $n$,  $n^2$ linear forms $M_{ij}$, $i,j=1,\ldots n$ in $n^2$ variables $X_{11}, \ldots X_{nn}$.
>
> *Problem:* Is there an assignement of values to the variables $X_{ij}$ so that the matrix $M_{ij}$ is invertible?

${}$

> **Question:** What is known about algorithms for this problem?

As usually, let's assume the addition and multiplication in the field to have computational cost $1$.

The naive algorithm of checking each assignment of the variables $X_{ij}$ takes time bounded by a polynomial in $p^{n^2}$. I'd be interested to know if there is an improvement to polynomial in $p^n$ (or better).

The special case when each $M_{ij}$ is equal either to $0$ or to $X_{ij}$ is solved  by Emil Jeřábek on the mathoverflow thread linked to below.

Comment: I've posted it also to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82804/determining-if-a-matrix-of-linear-forms-represents-a-non-degenerate-matrix

Comment: Google for "Polynomial identity testing"

Comment: @MarkusBläser: I wanted to give a similar answer as yours. Yet, I am not sure what can be said on this particular problem, in terms of a deterministic algorithm, using the current results on PIT.

Comment: @Bruno: Derandomizing the problem would imply circuit lower bounds. This problem is considered under the name SDIT (Symbolic Determinant Identity testing) by Kabanets & Impagliazzo. (Comput. Complexity 13, 2004)

Comment: @MarkusBläser: your previous comment should be made an answer. I would add that Gurvits has given a deterministic algorithm for some special cases of SDIT (http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/780542.780545). He refers to SDIT as "Edmonds' problem".

Answer (score 9):

This answer summarizes and expands my comments above:

1) If the size of the underlying field is large enough, then this problem has efficient randomized algorithms: You have to test whether the resulting determinant is nonzero as a polynomial. You can use the Schwartz-Zippel lemma for this. (Search for the keyword "Polynomial Identity testing"
for further algorithms/results.)

2) The question whether this problem can be derandomized is open.
Derandomizing it implies circuit lower bounds. See the work by Kabanets & Impagliazzo. (Comput. Complexity 13, 2004, http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~kabanets/Research/poly.html), the problem is called
SDIT (Symbolic Determinant Identity testing) in the paper.

3) Gurvits has a deterministic algorithm for some special cases of SDIT
(http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/780542.780545). He refers to SDIT as "Edmond's problem". (This item was provided by Joshua Grochow. I suggest that when 
you want to upvote my answer, you should upvote any of his answers with probability 1/4 instead.)

4) Over finite fields (size is fixed), it is NP-complete. Over GF(2), you can just arithmetize a given formula in 3-CNF (that is, write it as an equivalent arithmetic formula)
and then use fact that you can write any arithmetic formula as a poly-size determinant (proven by Valiant, see also Bürgisser, Clausen, Shokrollahi,
Algebraic Complexity Theory, Chapter 21). Over other finite fields, you can start with appropriate CSPs instead of 3-SAT.

Comment: "I suggest that when you want to upvote my answer, you should upvote any of his answers with probability 1/4 instead." <-- that made me smile. :-)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really answer the question whether you can improve from $p^{n^2}$ to p^n. See the discussion on mathoverflow - there it is shown how to embed instances of 3-SAT of size n into $n\times n$ matrix. But this just shows that one shoudn't hope for an algorithm better than p^n. I made it precise in [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82892/3-sat-and-linear-forms-representing-a-non-degenerate-matrix)